# S3 connection Pool TimeOut while Streaming

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having trouble streaming file back to client. I am fetching the file from s3 bucket fine. S3 connection pool is configured to be 1024. After 1024 requests, I am seeing "connect timeouts" to s3. I have a hunch there is a memory leak since I am not closing the s3 stream.

The thing is, since I have to serve up large pdf files, I can't load the data in memory in a bytes array. Is there is a way to stream the data back to client without causing this memory leak?

I tried loading the file in bytes[], closing the s3 stream using try with resource and streaming back to client using ByteArrayInputStream. That works fine but I don't want to load the whole file in memory since the size of files could be very large.

```
// Controller Code
@GetMapping(value = "/pdf")
public ResponseEntity getStatementPDF(@PathVariable("fileName") @AlphanumericIdConstraint String fileName) {
    ResponseEntity response = service.getPDF(fileName);

    log.info("Retrieved PDF file for fileName={}", fileName);
    return response;
}

// Service Layer Code
public ResponseEntity getPDF(String fileName) {
    S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject("bucket", fileName);
    InputStream stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
    InputStream decryptedFile = decryptor.decrypt(stream);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    httpHeaders.setContentDisposition(createContentDisposition(fileName));
    httpHeaders.set(CONTENT_ID_HEADER, fileName);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(decryptedFile), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.http.exception.HttpRequestTimeoutException: Request did not complete before the request timeout configuration.
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1250)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
```

Comment: Btw I am using Spring Boot framework. I was under the impression spring automatically closes the stream once the data is served to the client but apparently there is a resource leak.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your impression is wrong. Especially in your case you are using `S3Client` to open the stream, then do some operations and leave it open. If you think about it Spring doesn't have any way of closing it or even knowing about it.

However Spring also provides a [Spring Cloud AWS](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) integration which is a higher-level API for AWS services, but even this thing doesn't seem to be managing your IO for you 100% of time.

Aaaand the morale is: close your streams. :)

Comment: so essentially my only option is to load the whole file in bytes in memory and then return it to the client?